# ORA-01003: no statement parsed

Tags: java, oracle, servlets

i am trying to create a table as well as insert values on the same table on the same program. table is created and insert query is not done. i get the same error what ever i change i make to the insert string

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    Connection conn;
    Statement smt;
    ResultSet rs;
    String ses_id=(String) session.getAttribute("mailid");
    String add=request.getParameter("to_add");
    try
    {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","password");
        smt=conn.createStatement();
        System.out.println("connected");
        try
        {
            rs=smt.executeQuery("create table "+add+"_inbox(sender_id varchar(20), subject varchar(20), message varchar(4000))");
            System.out.println("created a table");
            while(rs.next())
            {

                smt.executeUpdate("insert into "+add+"_inbox(sender_id,subject,message)"+" values('"+ses_id+"','"+request.getParameter("sub")+"','"+request.getParameter("msg")+"')");
                System.out.println("done"); 
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("exception");
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }finally{}
}
```

I am using eclipse for servlet and oracle10g for db.
the database is connected, 
table is created created, 
insert query is not done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not enter the `while` loop because `rs` doesn't have any `rs.next` values. 
What do you want to insert in the table ? What I see is that you want to insert one row which parameters are from the `HttpSession` and `HttpServletRequest`. So remove your `while(rs.next)` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Because `executeQuery` always expects something will be returned.
So you could directly use `execute` method either for **creating** or **updating** tables.